# Problem downloading or installing anything from Software Center

Tags: 10.10, software-center

I've been trying for days now to install Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.10 but it never works. if I double click on Eclipse icon, it does nothing. I've tried to change permission and applying methods I found but none of them works. Also Software Center is not downloading or installing anything.
It shows errors similar to this one:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

OR

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: @Aditya Maybe not. If it's really 10.04, the problem is wrong repos. (Btw, 10.04 is still supported, even on the desktop. So if this turns out not to be a dupe of that, we can definitely still answer it.) **Aqsa Akbar**: You said you're running 10.04. But you have `maverick-backports` enabled. Maverick is 10.10. If you meant you're running 10.10, please let us know--that means this is a duplicate of that question. Otherwise, you should fix your mixed repositories; if you're running 10.04, please provide the output of `lsb_release -a` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` (edit your question).

Comment: ooops i have 10.10...

Comment: @eliah i checked that solution. i ran the commands and it gives these errors..                                                W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: The problem is that you have only incompletely followed the instructions at [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) (which this can now be closed as a duplicate of). You have to replace `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`, too. For example, if you're following [that answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/237118/22949), make sure to do step 5.

Comment: i did everything that post said but it still isn't working...

Comment: i had replaced the site address in sources but after that i wanted to install jdk, and it said that it cant find this package. same is the case with jre..

Answer (score 0):

Maverick is no longer supported, so the packages were moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com. Please upgrade to a newer version or modify your sources.list

Comment: Modifying the `sources.list` will fetch newer files for eclipse on an older Ubuntu, which is not recommended.

Comment: I meant pointing to old-releases.ubuntu.com, not changing from maverick to natty/oneiric/precise/quantal/raring.

Comment: The asker said he has 10.04 Lucid Linx which is an LTS edition, and still in support until the end of this month AFAIK.

Comment: Oh, missed that. Then they messed up their system already as it has maverick repositories enabled!

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel Actually, a bit longer--[through May 9th](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). (See [the official announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2013-March/000169.html) for details.) Even after that, lucid repositories won't go to the old-release server for years, though, because 10.04 LTS will remain supported on the server platform--so long as no community-maintained or GUI-related packages are used--through April 2015. (So far, LTS releases have been supported significantly longer for such server use.)

Comment: i cant upgrade.. i have tried it through terminal, update manager but it always stops for some reason..

Comment: @Dennis how can i update sources.list??

Comment: One more thing.. i lost a directory Movies approximately 45.0 GB.. i thought my sister misplaced it.. i have checked all directories(including trash) but cant find it.. if someone know answer to this question, do reply plz...